# How to change color of product in a picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion, image-editing

I have a picture of Jacket, the color of jacket is black. I want to change the jacket color to white. Here is the picture

[image]

How can I change the color of jacket ? Please help.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change black clothes into white](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68991/change-black-clothes-into-white)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's in a comment hinted the question is duplicate of an older case. But you have quite high resolution image which can be modified better than the image in the duplicate candidate.

Start by removing the background and desaturating.

[image]

Any color would be harmful because it would get distorted. White background maybe isn't optimal and it would also generate extra border in the process.

Make a duplicate of the image layer, stretch with curves its brightness range cover all from black to white:

[image]

Apply to the copy High Pass Filter to fade partially large area brightness differences but to save small area contrast. You may need the result to have something on areas which otherwise would become too near white:

[image]

The filtering unfortunately can lift up also noise. You can fight back by applying filter Smart Blur with few pixels radius and treshold so that important details, for ex. the zipper stay visible. It's used here, too.

Close the filtered layer temporarily. Insert an adjustment layer Curves to make the layer white except leave some darkness. You need to fix the adjustment later, so use adjustment layer. Do not worry if finest details fade when it's white enough.

[image]

Enable the filtered version, give to it blending mode Hard light and adjust its opacity and the curves adjustment layer until you have good balance between apparent whiteness and visible details. Do not worry if the visible interior area is too white.

[image]

You may want some areas to stay non-white. Make a selection in the original, copy and paste in place the wanted areas onto the top and adjust their greyshade with curves:

[image]

Colorization of the non-white areas is possible with Hue&Saturation. Adjustment layers with mask are very useful because the curves and colorization interact. Both should be adjusted.

The Curves adjustment in the previous step is Undone and adjustment layers are inserted. They get automatically right mask if you have the area selection ON. You need no masks if the adjustment layers have "the next image layer only"-switch ON.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much sir :)

Comment: Can you please share the psd file too ? Its a request

Comment: You can take it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/asb7n9ev90dorba/Whitened_Jacket.psd?dl=0 Do not expect you can publish or sell it without making it properly from the start. All selections  (=by the magic wand and the quick selection tool) and the general resolution are too coarse . It can be watched on the screen but it doesn't stand zooming in nor printing

Comment: Thank you sir, I will take care of the details.